# How to change Nan values to zero in a list of DataFrame in Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I want to change the Nan values in a specific column in a list of DataFrame. I have applied methods (below). I am not unable to change the nan to zero. Is there any way to replace the values to zero
Data is the list of DataFrame and qobs is the specific column in each DataFrame

```
for value in data:
    value['qobs']= value['qobs'].replace(np.nan,0)

for value in data:
    value['qobs']= value['qobs'].fillna(0)
```

Comment: `value['qobs'] = value['qobs'].fillna(0)`

Comment: @ansev I applied this method but it does  not work

Comment: add print(value) in your for loop,,, value is the name of columns...

Answer (score 0):

You can change column like this:

```py
data['qobs'] = data['qobs'].fillna(0)
print(data)
```